# How to get all user defined attributes in types.SimpleNamespace type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When doing:

```
import types
ns = types.SimpleNamespace(alfa = 1, bravo = 2, charlie = 3)
print(dir(ns))
```

The resulting list contains all the class methods also, thus:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', ..., 'alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie']
```

How to get a list of only the user defined attributes, thus `['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie']`, preferable without doing ridiculous text matching on the attribute names ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:**

Actually, I just remembered you can do:

```
>>> import types
>>> ns = types.SimpleNamespace(alfa = 1, bravo = 2, charlie = 3)
>>> list(ns.__dict__)
['charlie', 'bravo', 'alfa']
>>> sorted(ns.__dict__)
['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie']
>>>
```

which is a lot simpler.

---

Just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter the results:

```
>>> import types
>>> ns = types.SimpleNamespace(alfa = 1, bravo = 2, charlie = 3)
>>> [x for x in dir(ns) if not x.startswith('__')]
['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie']
>>>
```

Thankfully, all special methods/attributes begin and end with `__`, so they are easy to filter out.

If you want to allow names that only start with `__`, then you can make the `if` clause a little more robust:

```
[x for x in dir(ns) if not (x.startswith('__') and x.endswith('__'))]
```

Comment: Thanks, but is such text searching really required ?  Appears like the SimpleNamespace is harder to use than for example dict, which have e.g. keys to get the defined values.